# asp.net Webform Error Handling

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Which is the best way of handle error in asp.net?  Application level or 
Page level or Code level? can some one give links about best practice of error handling?

Comment: log4net or Nlog and custom error page for the user. Other than that try/catch in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle errors at each of those levels. [google search.](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp%20net%20web%20forms%20error%20handling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)